# Django views links not working

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to make a Django App where you can upload images to a portfolio. I've got my dashboard working, but when I click on my 'add new project' link, it just takes me back to the dashboard. What gives?

```
dashboard.html
<section class="bg-primary" id="header">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h2 class="section-heading">{{ title }}</h2>
                <a href="{% url 'projects:new' %}">Add Project.</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>

projects-urls.py
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^new/', views.new, name='new')
]

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('projects.urls', namespace='projects')),

views.py
def new(request):
    title = "Add Project"
    return HttpResponse("<h1>New Project</h1>")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate your URL patterns. Otherwise the first one matches everything, because a `^` on its own just means "any string that starts", which is obviously all of them.

```
url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
url(r'^new/$', views.new, name='new')
```

Note however you must not terminate the include pattern in the main urls.py.

Comment: Yes! Thank You, I can't believe I didn't do that eariler!